# Can a pitched roof be built over a rubber roof memberane on a 16x60 single wide mobile home?

Tags: roof, addition

I am looking to add some extra storage space,and add on a room to my mobile home. We had the rubber roof membrane replaced in 2020 and own the mobile home. I already have park approval to add a room onto my home. What I am wondering is if I can basically add some attic space when I add the new room with how I build the roof. I was thinking of adding onto of the current roof, a pitched roof with like 6ft in the center, and this would span the width of the home plus the addition. Is this structurally possible with a 1970 flat roof? The home has been pretty well taken care of over the years, so the walls are solid, and so is the frame.

Comment: The weight would end up transferring to the outer walls. If they were not designed for that weight, this would not be a good idea.

Comment: Yes, adding weight on the roof of a manufactured home is Not Going To Work.  Since the home is well cared-for, sell it and buy one that is the size you need. Consider a non-manufactured home so you can get away from the park rental.

Comment: I do not think that the rubber membrane roof is meant to walk on, so you need to build a floor.

Answer (score 1):

It could be build but not using the current roof as support structure since you plan to load it up and walk on it.

Using aluminum or steal construction where the new roof sits on vertical beams from the ground and building the suspended floor over the current roof would work.